# Is there a way to turn the eventargs argument from a textbox into a string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

This is my first real project in C# with windows forms and i am trying to know if the number of letters inputted into my textbox is superior to 11, so i used

```
if (e[10] != null)
```

But i quickly realized this was only possible for strings and "e" is not a string but an "EventArgs" type. Is there any way to get a string from it?

Comment: Depends on the event. `EventArgs` is a very basic type. So it won't carry much information. You should probably get the text from the `sender` of your event ... Furhtermore `somestring[10]` will throw an exception, if the string is not at least 11 characters long

Comment: Cast the sender to TextBox, then get Text.Length

Comment: `if (int.TryParse((sender as TextBox).Text, out int value)) { // evaluate value }`

Comment: In addition to the other (excellent) comments, as a general rule, if you examine the properties of the specific `EventArgs`-derived class, you should find it has some useful properties. Specifically, you will usually find the data for the control in question  (in this case, the text form the textbox).

Comment: Assuming your textbox is name `textBox1`, to check length of text entered in the textbox, you can do `if(textBox1.Text.Length >10)`, then you can show afirendly message like: `MessageBox.Show("More than 10 characters?!Why?! ");`

Answer (score 0):

Not all the event args are useful; usually the useful ones are those who are special types like [MouseEventArg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), or [FormClosingEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) which carry some useful information about the event, like the point that mouse has been clicked, or how the form is closing, and etc.

So here, you don't need converting event arg to string or try to read anything out of it. The information you are looking for is not there.

In many cases, you just need information from your controls, for example here you are interested in input length, so no matter which event handler you are using (Click event of a Button, or TextChanged event of a TextBox) you can check the properties of your TextBox. Here assuming `textBox1` is the one you are interested in, just check the length of its [Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.text?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property like the following, and show a *friendly* validation message if it's longer than expected:

```
if(textBox1.Text.Length >10)
{
    MessageBox.Show("More than 10 characters?!Why?! ");
}
```

**Some quick notes:**

- If the event arg has special type, check the properties of `e` to see if there's anything useful there
- The sender parameter is the control which has raised the event, for example on a click event on a button, it's the button, or in text changed event of a text box, it's the text box, so you can unbox and use it like `var btn = (Button)sender;`.
- No matter who the sender is, you can check everything there, for example check properties of another control, like `textBox1.Text`